# How to add shape keys with two different audio

Tags: shape-keys, audio, fcurves

I am trying to add shape keys to mouth of my character with audio file. But when I try to add second audio to the same character, the shape keys aren't working. I also added "bake audio to F curves" so that it is in correct lipsync. So how do I add another shape key using second audio and lipsync my character

[image]

Comment: could you attach a sample .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=N5eGd2wB" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/N5eGd2wB/)